# UN- REVIVABLE in Trademarks

Tags: united-states, trademark

Status/Status date:12/19/2014: Continued use not filed within grace period, UN-REVIVABLE

In US does that mean registrant can never register this trademark?

Can another entity register this mark for the same purpose?